# ListView not accepting Stack but works with List

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I am trying to populate a ListView with IHistoryItem object. Since the history should work LIFO, I decided to use a `Stack<T>` as my collection:

```
private readonly Stack<IHistoryItem> history = new Stack<IHistoryItem>();
```

Now when I try to populate my ListView with the Stack, it doesn't show any items:
*Note: There is no Error/Warning/Exception, just nothing.*

```
this.lvHistory.ItemsSource = this.history;
```

However, when I use the following code, it works:

```
this.lvHistory.ItemsSource = this.history.ToList();
```

To the real question: **Why is this the case?**

Since the `.ToList()` doesn't sync with the original Stack, I have to set the binding every time the Stack changes, instead of calling `lvHistory.UpdateLayout();`.  Is there a better way?

The ListView looks like this in XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvHistory" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" MinHeight="150">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type history:IHistoryItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListViewString}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

IHistoryItem looks like this:

```
public interface IHistoryItem
{
    #region Events
    event EventHandler ActionRedone;

    event EventHandler ActionUndone;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    string ListViewString { get; }
    #endregion

    void Redo();

    void Undo();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  Of course only for those items that are already contained in the Stack before it is assigned to ItemsSource. Otherwise you would need an observable Stack, similar to ObservableCollection<T>. As a note, you don't need to set an ItemTemplate's DataType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since implementing an `ObservableStack<T>` is a bit overkill for this problem I went down another path.
It had nothing to do with the `Stack<T>` itself, but that the `ItemsSource` wasn't reloaded because it was "still the same".
This fixes that issue:

```
this.lvHistory.ItemsSource = null;
this.lvHistory.ItemsSource = this.history;
```

Thanks to @Clemens for the eye-opener.

Comment: Note however that this will re-generate all items in the ListView, which may get annoying when there are many.

Comment: That's a useful thing to keep in mind, true. However in my case there should never be "many" items in the Stack. Thanks @Clemens